# Objective-C: How to return to beginning of application after switch statement is complete

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios, loops, switch-statement

For example,

In your program you have:

```
NSLog(@"Where are you going?");
NSLog(@" 1 = Location1, 2 = Location2");

printf("Make a selection:");

scanf("%i, &value);

switch (value) {
    case 1:
        NSLog(@"You are going to Location 1.")
        break;

    case 2:
        NSLog(@"You are going to Location 2.");
        break;

    default:
        NSLog(@"That is not a valid location");
        break;
}
```

---

Normally after you input your integer your program will return 0 and the application ends. How do you go about having it "loop" back to the original printf to make a new selection. Or even better, a new printf IE 'printf("Where else would you like to go?:");'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you keep it as a separate method and call it from itself when you want to loop. Just consider the following code,

```
void takeMeToPlaces() {

    NSLog(@"Where are you going?");
    NSLog(@"0 = Exit, 1 = Location1, 2 = Location2");

    printf("Make a selection:");

    scanf("%i, &value);

    switch (value) {
        case 0:
            NSLog(@"You don't like to go anywhere");
            break;

        case 1:
            NSLog(@"You are going to Location 1.");
            takeMeToPlaces();
            break;

        case 2:
            NSLog(@"You are going to Location 2.");
            takeMeToPlaces();
            break;

        default:
            NSLog(@"That is not a valid location");
            takeMeToPlaces();
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: in that way you can potentially garbage function's call stack. Better use a simple `for(;;){}` loop (as example)